# How to get change event in extjs textfield picker

Tags: javascript, extjs, picker

I want to extend an extension from Extjs picker. I want to when user type a text in picker, call a function. I use `change` event, It does not work.

I want to extend an extension like combobox, When you type a text, it filter records.

How can I implement it?

Comment: Can you show me where did you add the 'change' listener?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Ext.define('MyExtension', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Picker',

    // config...

    listeners: {
        change: {
            fn: function (picker, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
                // your code here
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You can also refer to a function in your viewcontroller (Extjs5/6)

```
listeners: {
        change: {
            fn: 'myViewControllerFunction'
    }
```

If this does not work either you should show us parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite `onChange` property in your extension, like this:

```
onChange: function() {
            // Your logic
            console.log('Changed!');

            // Call parent method onChange(), if needed
            this.callParent();
}
```

I create simple fiddle to illustrate how it works - [onChange() method fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13n4)

Comment: I create fiddle for you and add it to my answer, check it please. If I understand your issue wrong - feel free to fork and show what exactly you need.

Answer (score 0):

Add a 'change' listener to your picker(it can be a combobox, a date picker, etc...)

Here is an example:

```
var comboName = new Ext.form.field.ComboBox({
  fieldLabel: 'Name',
  editable: true,
  listeners: {
    'change': function (this, newValue, oldValue) {
     DoSomething();
    }
  }
});
```

The previous code will call DoSomething() function everytime you change the value.

Answer (score -1):

If you extended `Ext.form.field.Picker` class, 'change' event should be handled like this:

```
Ext.define('Your.extended.ClassName', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Picker',

    ...

    onChange: function(newVal, oldVal) {
        ....
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```